# Can you explain the output in this C program?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char ch[] = { "chicken is good" };
    char str[100];
    while ((str[i++] = ch[j++]) != '\0') {
        if (i == strlen(str))
            break;
    }
    printf("%s", str);
}
```

I want to copy the string `"chicken is good"` from `ch` to `str` using a `while` loop. But when I print `str` the output shows `"chi"`. It only prints part of the string. Is my condition wrong?

I am using Dev c++ as my IDE and the version of my compiler is gcc 4.9.2. And also I am new to programming.

Comment: Delete `if(i == strlen(str))
            break`

Comment: I got it @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen(str)` has undefined behaviour, because it is reading uninitialized values.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `if (i == strlen(str)) break;` is useless and has undefined behavior since `str` is not yet null terminated.

Note that your program has other problems:

- you must specify the return value of the `main` function as `int`. You are using an obsolete syntax.
- you do not need separate index variables `i` and `j` for the source and destination arrays. They always have the same value.
- you should print a newline at the end of your message.
- for good style, you should return `0` at the end of `main()`.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;
    char ch[] = "chicken is good";
    char str[100];

    for (i = 0; (str[i] = ch[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        continue;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer and showing all my flaws @chqrlie